# A relatively relativity-safe FTL

Tags: science-based, space-travel, faster-than-light

Relativity is fun, but it does have some downsides. In practice, travelling near the speed of light makes you travel into the future, which is problematic.

Relativity also doesn't seem to agree with the concept of FTL travel, which is embarrassing because light is pretty slow for galactic travel.

My idea is to generate a bubble of hyperspace, in which physics misbehave in a convenient manner. The one major rule is that the speed of light in hyperspace is tweakable somehow, which is to say it will be always much higher than your speed, but also can be higher than itself in vacuum.

Of note, hyperspace will break when getting too close from a gravity well. When the hyperspace bubble collapses, you could be completely torn apart, or in a best case scenario sent wildly off-course in the galaxy next door.

My goal is to:

A) Preserve causality in all circumstances. Time travel should be excluded, although technically, if things where to go wrong, you could maybe possibly theoretically find yourself in the future on arrival.

B) Severely limit time dilation. My understanding is time dilation can't be prevented completely, but the rule of thumb should be that if time dilation makes you more than fashionably late, it's too much.

Is my hyperspace allowing that? Is there anything else I'm breaking beyond relativity?

Comment: My guess is that you're already breaking physics, but in a *suspention of disbelief*-friendly way, so you could make all the assumptions you want on that point :)

Comment: It's impossible to have FTL without breaking causality and introducing time travel. Your idea is core element of titular mass effect in Mass Effect series. It's not possible or practical, but problems are hidden deep enough that science-casuals don't realise them.

Comment: @StigHemmer I'm gonna be honest, I read that and I'm not really confident I understood half of it. What I took from it is your medium shouldn't allow you to go back in time somehow.

Comment: Also by standing still one travels into the future, simply because we are not able to control our movement in time

Comment: "I want to travel forward in time, but without time travel" ?? Moving Faster Than Light *is* time travel

Comment: If your hyperspace bubble violates Lorentz invariance, then all your relativity troubles go away. Causality is preserved & no time travel worries. However, you will lose time dilation too. You will need to travel fast otherwise you will grow old going to the stars.